# Are there cases where we need to avoid the usage of IQR?

Tags: standard-deviation, interquartile, mean-absolute-deviation

Let's consider the interquartile range (IQR), the standard deviation (SD) and the mean absolute deviation (MAD). We know that "[one of the most common robust measures of scale is the interquartile range (IQR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale)", while the "[standard deviation, is greatly influenced by outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale)", with "[a breakdown point of 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_measures_of_scale)". Also, "[The mean absolute deviation is a measure of dispersion more robust than the standard deviation](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-0-387-32833-1_250)".

In cases where I calculate IQR, SD and MAD in approximately symmetric or moderately skewed distributions (with no outliers), SD and MAD give similar values (MAD returns a bit lower values than SD), and they are always lower than IQR values, and relatively far from IQR values.

Probably, nothing is wrong to keep both IQR, SD and MAD, since they are just different definitions of the word "dispersion", but if a person needs to rely on one number indicating the dispersion of the data and asks, "what is the dispersion of that distribution?", should we say all the values of IQR, SD and MAD?

Or should we - for example - discard IQR, since quite far from SD and MAD, and just communicate either SD or MAD, since quite close to each other?

From this case, I would generalise and ask: Are there cases where we need to avoid the usage of IQR?

Comment: For a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ (rather than a sample from a normal distribution), the standard deviation is then $\sigma$, the mean absolute deviation  $\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\sigma \approx 0.80 \, \sigma$, the median absolute deviation $\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac34\right)\,\sigma \approx 0.67\, \sigma$, and the interquartile range $2\,\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac34\right)\,\sigma \approx 1.35\, \sigma$.  They are all proportional to scale and will usually vary with the shape of the distribution you are looking at.

Comment: Thanks for your commetn @Henry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, there's no reason IQR ought to be close to SD or MAD. While they are all measuring some aspect of dispersion, they are doing it in very different ways. An analogy might be that height, width, and depth are all measures of the size of an object, but there's no reason for them to agree. (Not a perfect analogy, I admit).

Second, if a person asks, "what is the dispersion of that distribution?" then we should investigate the distribution and talk to the person about what they want. There is no one right answer. Sometimes, there is *no* right, or even good, numeric answer and we will need to show a graph or use more than one measure.  They may *want* a single measure, but  .... you can't always get what you want, but if you ask a good data analyst, you'll get what you need.

Third, although some people give the IQR as a single number (Q3 - Q1), I prefer to give both numbers. That gives more information.

Finally, we should avoid IQR when it does not answer the needs of the person. This depends only partially on the shape of the distribution. But, e.g. there are cases where Q1, Q2 (median) and Q3 are all the same, but there are a few extreme outliers. There, it seems unlikely that the IQR is an answer to a question that the person could have (but it might be!)

Comment: I love the last sentence of your second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter Flom! :-)

Comment: Since the interquartile range (IQR) just refers to the central half of the distribution $-$ contrary to the standard deviation that takes values from the whole distribution $-$, could the usage of IQR be misleading when used for symmetric or approximate symmetric distributions? Indeed, in some books, I read that it is usually recommended to use mean+standard deviation for symmetric distributions and median+interquartile range for non-symmetric distributions. I mean, I understand the recommendation for "median+interquartile range for a non-symmetric dist.", but not that one for symmetric dist.

Comment: How could it be misleading?   The mean and SD have some nice properties when the distribution is symmetric, but that doesn't make the IQR misleading.